# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' Angular 6 and FIrebase

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angular6

**Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'.
**

I am trying to do unsubscribe the observable

Angular-cli = 6.0.3

> HTML home.component.html

```
<div class="starter-template">
  <h1>Firebase Data</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses$ | async">
      {{ course.$value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Typescript  home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent {
  courses$;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.courses$ = db.list('/course');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The doc (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#retrieve-data) says you need to use `.valueChanges()`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
       {{ item | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();
  }
}
```